# VB.NET Treeview Nodes

Tags: vb.net, treeview

VB.NET
Windows 7

How can I drag and drop nodes in a tree view BETWEEN root nodes in the SAME tree view?
I can get it to drop a parent onto another parent which then makes it a child of the dropped on parent but I also need to be able to drag a parent in BETWEEN other parents.

Comment: possible duplicate of [VB.Net Live TreeView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24374554/vb-net-live-treeview)

Comment: Are you talking about re-ordering the parent nodes?

Comment: Yes. Currently I'm able to drag and drop but when I drag and drop a parent node it makes it a child of another parent. I need to be able to drag and drop between parent nodes. For example, if I have :
1
2
3
4
and I want to drag 3 above 2, I can't get that to happen.